# vue3: new value and old value returned by deep watcher always same

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

```js
const app = {
  data(){
    return {
      form: {
        name: '',
        password: ''
      }
    } 
  },
  watch: {
    form: {
      handler(form, oldForm){
        console.log(form, oldForm);
      },
      deep: true
    } 
  }
}

Vue.createApp(app).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<main id="app">
  <form>
    <input v-model="form.name"/>
    <input v-model="form.password"/>
  </form>
</main>
```

I got a deep watcher for an object value, accroding to the [document](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/computed-watch-api.html#watch), it should get both the previous and current value of the object been watched.

But in this code, the new value and the old value returned by the deep watcher are always same. Why is that?

Thanks a lot for anyone help!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ref: [watch](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/instance-methods.html#watch)

> Note: when mutating (rather than replacing) an Object or an Array and watch with deep option, the old value will be the same as new value because they reference the same Object/Array. Vue doesn't keep a copy of the pre-mutate value.

Comment: key diffirence is use `() => ({ ...form }),` instead of `() => form` when define watch

Answer (score 16):

Use setup to watch instead...

```js
import {reactive} from 'vue'

setup() {
  const form = reactive({
      name: '',
      password: ''
  })

  watch(
        () => ({ ...form }),
        (newVal, oldVal) => {
            console.log('Form changed', newVal, oldVal)
        }
    )

  return {
    form
  }
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? Vue doesn't store the previous value anywhere, and as `reactive()` creates a reference type, once it's changed, the old value is gone forever... To get around this, you could use the `toRef()` Vue function for each item in the `reactive` object, but that kind of defeats the point of using `reactive` in the first place. I'm wondering why this has as many up-votes as it does?

Comment: You saved my day! Nice answer. This works very well for `reactive` objects. I tried a lot of stuff with no luck.